# ui-select binding not working when choosing another item

Tags: angular, metronic

I have created a phoneInput directive which has a ui-select element for picking the desire country code and an input element for the phone number.

the ui-select element looks like this:

```
<ui-select ng-model="selectedCountryPhone" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default'}">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="{{'IMPORT_USERS.COUNTRY_PLACEHOLDER' | translate}}">
            <span>{{$select.selected.phone}}</span>
        </ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="country.phone as country in (countries | filter: $select.search)" >
            <span>{{country.name}}({{country.phone}})</span>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
```

I am able to initiate the model `selectedCountryPhone` in the directive but when i'm trying to choose another country from the list it shows that I've picked the new country code but the value of `selectedCountryPhone` is still the init value...

Comment: try `ng-model="Person.selectedCountryPhone"` instead of `ng-model="selectedCountryPhone"`

Comment: @pandian_Snkl , I don't understand this solution

Comment: @kitsuneFox- ui select model some time not updating when we put straight object like ` "selectedCountryPhone"` . So Use defined object (alredy mention `$scope.person={};` in controller) maybe work..